# How to make Text Scaling in Chrome Accessibility work in non-desktop mode to make fonts smaller?

Tags: chrome-for-android, accessibility

When I use text scaling and reduce it to 50%, it remains the same in normal mobile site mode. It only reduces the size in desktop mode.

Is there any way to configure this size? In Firefox, I can see much more content due to smaller fonts than in Chrome.

Comment: It does work for me (Pixel 4a, Android 11).Is your Chrome updated?